# Short-Term Option Contract Worth Same as Long Term Option Contract At Same Strike?

Tags: options, american-options

Let's say that I'm analyzing option contracts for ABC Company, which typically trades at lower volumes. While researching ABC Company, I notice that for a given strike price, contracts that expire in 3 months have recently traded at nearly the same price level as contracts that expire in 6 months. Both contracts were ITM and had higher IV.

I understand that ABC Company trades at lower volumes, and it could just be a fluke, but wouldn't the contract that expires in 6 months be worth more on time value alone? If I'm long the shorter-term contract, wouldn't it make sense to close the position and then go long on the longer-term contract (maybe even sell the shorter-term contract)? Or, alternatively, would I close it out and leave the longer-term contract alone since I'm ITM and still have time value to capture on the short-term contact? Maybe the market believes the price of the underlying will be unchanged 3 to 6 months out.

Strangely enough, I should note that I estimated the price of both contracts using BSM, and both are trading near their BSM valuations.

Comment: If the options trade infrequently the prices of options you observe may have a lag. For example the price of option 1 might be for a trade this morning, the price of option 2 might be for a trade 5 minutes ago, this afternoon. It might be better to look at bid-ask midpoint rather than traded price.

Comment: I think that this captures some of the essence of what was going on. The 3-month option and 6-month option had differing last trade dates, so the last trade prices were not representative of the current condition. The bid-ask midpoint was certainly better, but still a bit off (low volume issue?). Today the 6-month option was trading at a higher price. Doesn't exactly explain the BSM valuation situation, which coincidentally matched-up closely to both last trade prices yesterday, but oh well. Perhaps it truly was a profit opportunity. I know better for next time.